# appendix LOT after general LOT

Tags: table-of-contents

I wish to create two LOF lists (also two LOT), one of the major files and one of the files in the appendix. Generally speaking it worked well. But i wish to have both lists at the front of my Thesis one after another, sadly though i can only create the appendix-LOF at the beginning of my appendix not earlier.

How can i work this out? Or is there no way to move the LOF/LOT when using it like so?

"minimalcode" is :

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}


\usepackage{titletoc}


\begin{document} 


\tableofcontents  
\thispagestyle{empty}
\startlist[main]{lof}% starts main list of figures
\printlist[main]{lof}{}{\section*{List of Figures - general}}% prints main list of figures

\thispagestyle{empty}
%\listoftables
%\renewcommand{\listoftables}{Timetables}
%\listoffigures


\setcounter{page}{1}




\bibliography{scibib}

\bibliographystyle{AM}



\end{document}
```

i dont want to create a real appendix because i`m using the include option to section my appendix and the appendix feature seems to not be compatible with that? 
Anyway the code i`m using in the appendix looks like this :

```
\stoplist[main]{lof}% stops main list of figures

\section{Appendix}
\startlist[appendix]{lof}% starts list of figures in appendices
\printlist[appendix]{lof}{}{\section*{List of Figures in 
Appendix}}% prints list of figures in appendices
```

Comment: Please trim down your example to something that's really minimal. Your document is uncompilable by anyone but you because of all the `\include` commands you are using. And most of the packages you are loading are not relevant to the problem at hand, so you should remove them.

Comment: The simplest way to do this would be to define a separate float type for appendix tables. See [How to make two list of tables?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/25711) for how to do this.

Comment: Sorry i tried to shorten the minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using package `tocbasic`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  listname={List of Figures in Appendix},
  setup=totoc% add an entry in TOC for this list
]{alof}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  listname={List of Tables in Appendix},
  setup=totoc% add an entry in TOC for this list
]{alot}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\useappendixlists}{%
  \renewcommand*{\ext@figure}{alof}%
  \renewcommand*{\ext@table}{alot}%
}
\newcommand*{\usestandardlists}{%
  \renewcommand*{\ext@figure}{lof}%
  \renewcommand*{\ext@table}{lot}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents  
\listoffigures
\listofalofs

\clearpage
\section{A section}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\rule{\linewidth}{1cm}
\caption{First Figure}%
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\rule{\linewidth}{1cm}
\caption{Second Figure}%
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\section{Appendix}
\useappendixlists
\begin{figure}[htb]
\rule{\linewidth}{1cm}
\caption{First Figure in Appendix}%
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\rule{\linewidth}{1cm}
\caption{Second Figure in Appendix}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But note, that you can not use `tocbasic` together with package `titletoc` or package`tocloft`.

Comment: that worked really great thank you!
only one issue, the List of Appendix Figures is in my TOC, while i could remove the other lists from the TOC.  Any idea why that is?

Comment: +1 `tocbasic` is a very nice package.

Comment: @Ne-Ko-T If there should be no entry in TOC for the List of Appendix Figures remove`setup=totoc` from the options of `\DeclareNewTOC`.

Comment: wonderful! thank you very much it works perfectly now